# How can I change the Initial position of my geometry in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I would like to change the initial position where my geometry appears; Right now it appears in the center of the canvas. I would like it to appear at the left upper corner. Can you help me?

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.z = 1000;
```

Here is the full code:
[Three js example](https://jsfiddle.net/3eau15pv/)

Answer (score 1):

Change the position of the cube using `mesh.position.set(x, y, z)`

I used `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` to move your object to the corner of the screen.

Here is an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3eau15pv/1/) with your box in the upper-left corner of the screen.

If you don't like how the cube flies around when you drag it, you can't use `orbitControls` any more. To make the cube still rotate normally, use this code (jQuery required):

```
var isDragging = false;
var previousMousePosition = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};
$(renderer.domElement).on('mousedown', function(e) {
    isDragging = true;
})
.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    //console.log(e);
    var deltaMove = {
        x: e.offsetX-previousMousePosition.x,
        y: e.offsetY-previousMousePosition.y
    };

    if(isDragging) {

        var deltaRotationQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion()
            .setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(
                toRadians(deltaMove.y * 1),
                toRadians(deltaMove.x * 1),
                0,
                'XYZ'
            ));

        mesh.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(deltaRotationQuaternion, mesh.quaternion);
    }

    previousMousePosition = {
        x: e.offsetX,
        y: e.offsetY
    };
});

$(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    isDragging = false;
});
function toRadians(angle) {
    return angle * (Math.PI / 180);
}

function toDegrees(angle) {
    return angle * (180 / Math.PI);
}
```

Source for this code: https://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/n6u6asza/

Example using your code: https://jsfiddle.net/3eau15pv/3/